# where can i find product packaging information data?

Tags: data-request, data.gov, uses-of-open-data, releasing-data

where can i find the dataset about world products packaging components information? For example, the packaging of coke-cola is label, plastic bottle and plastic cap. where can i find such information which is saved in csv file?

Comment: Can you add more examples? It's not exactly clear to me what packaging data you want. Do you want the materials of the package components? Do you want amounts (weight)? How much data points? In what format? And what products? I doubt you want everything that's ever made... Please read [this guide](https://opendata.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/284/how-a-good-data-request-question-should-look-like) for more info, and [edit] your question.

Comment: probably the question above falls under the scope of this one --> https://opendata.stackexchange.com/q/9937/1511

Answer (score 0):

GS1 coordinates development of global trade code sets.

Specifically I believe you want this GS1 code set, https://www.gs1.org/voc/PackagingMaterialTypeCode. 
[image: GS1 - Packaging Material Type Code]